# How to kill Brayko in Alpha Protocol

Tags: alpha-protocol

I'm finding it very difficult to get through the Brayko boss fight in Alpha Protocol. Up to that point I'd only been dying once every few missions, but I've died about 5 or 6 times trying to get past Brayko.

I've been playing on easy because;

- I was trying to avoid this kind of aggravation, and
- I'm not all that good at shooters so I was quite surprised to run in to this kind of brick wall.

I've hit him with grenades, incendiary bombs and hundreds of assault rifle rounds, but nothing seems to stop him.

What method should I use to kill him? Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This video walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRojSYNg7k0) (warning, some NSFW dialogue!) recommends that you:

- Do not fight him during his coked up phase, as he regains all his armor
- Run away and get him tired as opposed to going gun-ho
- Conserve health pills carefully

Good luck!

Comment: "This video contains content from Sony Music Entertainment. It is no longer available in your country."

Comment: @NoCanDo Still up for me. Seems to a regional issue; gonna see if I can screen-capture it and upload without any sound so it won't get taken down.

Comment: Yes indeed, what part of "in your country" don't you get?

Comment: @NoCanDo Ha! You're right, it was incredibly stupid of me to say "seems to a regional issue" not only because I forgot the "be" but also because it's immediately obvious from the description. I might as well blow my brains out on the spot, yes indeed, only it seems I have none.

Answer (score 2):

I defeated Brayko using a combination of methods recommended for other bosses in the game, plus some methods custom to Brayko.

If you have already met Steven Heck (i.e. have done Taiwan missions), and have good reputation with him, then you can buy some help from him.  The Clearinghouse Intel choice which supplies Brayko with poisoned cocaine will help you during this boss fight.  Brayko won't get "coked up," instead his health will drain during that stage of the fight.

While Brayko is on stage, wait until he is reloading.  Use that time to place an incendiary or fragmentation grenade on the wall you are covering behind.  Return to cover.  Later in the boss fight, Brayko is likely to trigger this trap.

When shooting Brayko on the stage, use weaker ammo in order to save steel rounds or ADPS.  Brayko leaves the stage after a set amount of damage.  Once Brayko has left the stage, use armor-piercing ammo such as steel core bullets or ADPS.

If you have Shadow Operative for 20 seconds or longer, you can prevent Brayko from finding you for the duration of this fight.  Hide in the alcoves on either end of the open area.  It is useful to trap the entrances with grenades.  An outer incendiary grenade will take down his endurance.  A shock-trap within the entrance ensures that Thorton can escape with Shadow Operative or just running behind Brayko's back.  If possible, use a Chain Shot during Brayko's paralysis to take down his health, then escape.

I set traps on both alcoves, lured Brayko into each, and Chain Shot him (two shots) with Steel Core bullets, then escaped to the other alcove.  This reliably defeated him, using Shadow Operative 20 second duration to escape.

In general, the Chain Shot is very useful against bosses in Alpha Protocol.

Answer (score 2):

One nice trick that worked for me is leaving one of the summoned henchmen alive.  This seems to prevent more waves from coming.  You'll get shot up a bit while running away from knives-out Brayko, but if you're wearing decent armor it shouldn't be anything to worry about.  With that established, I just had to wait on my Chain Shot timer to break through Brayko's armor and take him down.